# Learning to multithread in C++: Adding threads doesn't make execution faster even though it seems like it should

Tags: c++, multithreading

To make a long story short, I ran into the [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) and was interested in throwing something together so I could test it computationally. That worked out fine, but in the process I got curious about multithreading applications in C++. I'm a CS student, but I've only covered that topic briefly with a different language. I wanted to see if I could utilize some of my extra CPU cores to make the Monte Hall simulation go a bit faster.

It seems like I got it working, but alas it doesn't actually have any performance increase. The program performs a large number of iterations over a simple function that essentially boils down to a few rand_r() calls and a couple comparisons. I would expect it to be a trivial example of something that could be split between threads, basically just having each thread handle an equal fraction of the total iterations.

I'm just trying to understand this, and I'm wondering if I'm making a mistake or if there's something going on in the background that's multithreading the execution even if I'm only specifying 1 thread in the code.

Anyway, take a look and share your thoughts. Please also bear in mind that I'm just doing this as a learning experience and didn't originally plan for anyone else to read it :D

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

enum strategy {STAY = 0, SWITCH = 1};
unsigned ITERATIONS = 1;
unsigned THREADS = 5;

struct counts
{
    unsigned stay_correct_c;
    unsigned switch_correct_c;
};

void simulate (struct counts&, unsigned&);
bool game (enum strategy, unsigned&);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " -i [t|s|m|l|x] -t [1|2|4|5|10]\n", exit(1);

    if (argv[1][1] == 'i') {
        switch (argv[2][0]) {
    case 's':
            ITERATIONS = 1000;
            break;
        case 'm':
            ITERATIONS = 100000;
            break;
        case 'l':
            ITERATIONS = 10000000;
            break;
        case 'x':
            ITERATIONS = 1000000000;
            break;
        default:
            std::cerr << "Invalid argument.\n", exit(1);
        }
    }

    if (argv[3][1] == 't') {
        switch (argv[4][0])
        {
        case '1':
            if (argv[4][1] != '0')
                THREADS = 1;
            else if (argv[4][1] == '0')
                THREADS = 10;
            break;
        case '2':
            THREADS = 2;
            break;
        case '4':
            THREADS = 4;
            break;
        case '5':
            THREADS = 5;
            break;
        }
    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    struct counts total_counts;
    total_counts.stay_correct_c = 0;
    total_counts.switch_correct_c = 0;
    struct counts per_thread_count[THREADS];
    std::thread* threads[THREADS];
    unsigned seeds[THREADS];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < THREADS; ++i) {
        seeds[i] = rand() % UINT_MAX;
        threads[i] = new std::thread (simulate, std::ref(per_thread_count[i]), std::ref(seeds[i]));
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < THREADS; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Waiting for thread " << i << " to finish...\n";
        threads[i]->join();
    }

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < THREADS; ++i) {
        total_counts.stay_correct_c += per_thread_count[i].stay_correct_c;
        total_counts.switch_correct_c += per_thread_count[i].switch_correct_c;
    }

    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout <<
        "The simulation performed " << ITERATIONS <<
        " iterations on " << THREADS << " threads of both the stay and switch strategies " <<
        "taking " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop - start).count() <<
        " ms." << std::endl <<
        "Score:" << std::endl <<
        "  Stay Strategy: " << total_counts.stay_correct_c << std::endl <<
        "  Switch Strategy: " << total_counts.switch_correct_c << std::endl << std::endl <<
        "Ratios:" << std::endl <<
        "  Stay Strategy: " << (double)total_counts.stay_correct_c / (double)ITERATIONS << std::endl <<
        "  Switch Strategy: " << (double)total_counts.switch_correct_c / (double)ITERATIONS << std::endl << std::endl;
}

void simulate (struct counts& c, unsigned& seed)
{
    c.stay_correct_c = 0;
    c.switch_correct_c = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < (ITERATIONS / THREADS); ++i) {
        if (game (STAY, seed))
            ++c.stay_correct_c;
        if (game (SWITCH, seed))
            ++c.switch_correct_c;
    }
}

bool game (enum strategy player_strat, unsigned& seed)
{
    unsigned correct_door = rand_r(&seed) % 3;
    unsigned player_choice = rand_r(&seed) % 3;
    unsigned elim_door;
    do {
        elim_door = rand_r(&seed) % 3;
    }
    while ((elim_door != correct_door) && (elim_door != player_choice));
    seed = rand_r(&seed);
    if (player_strat == SWITCH) {
        do
            player_choice = (player_choice + 1) % 3;
        while (player_choice != elim_door);
        return correct_door == player_choice;
    }
    else
        return correct_door == player_choice;
}
```

Edit: Going to add some supplementary information on the suggestion of some solid comments below.

I'm running on a 6 core/12 thread AMD Ryzen r5 1600. Htop shows the number of logical cores at high utilization that you would expect from the command line arguments. Number of PID's was the same as the number of threads specified plus one, and the number of logical cores with utilization ~= 100% was the same as number of threads specified in every case.

In terms of numbers, here are some data that I gathered using the l flag for a large number of iterations:

```
CORES    AVG      MIN      MAX
1     102541   102503   102613
4      90183    86770    96248
10     72119    63581    91438
```

With something as simple to divide as this program, I would have expected to see a linear decrease in total time as I added threads, but I'm clearly missing something. My thinking was that if 1 thread could perform x simulations in y time, that thread should be able to perform x/4 simulations in y/4 time. What am I misunderstanding here?

Edit 2: I should add that as the code exists above, the difference in time was less noticeable with different threads, but I made a couple small optimizations that made the delta a little larger.

Comment: There is one grave problem with your question: You say you expect a performance increase but that you don't get one. This is an interpretation, but actual numbers are missing! Further, the execution parameters are missing, too! Lastly, two possible reasons for not performing: Firstly, not enough CPU cores. Watch a system monitor while executing that this is actually distributed! Secondly, whenever you have multiple arrays of N elements that each correspond, chances are that your code is cleare when compbining them in a struct and it makes it easier on the CPU caches!

Comment: Well put: multithreaded problems often start with something that "seems like it should" work, but doesn't. One of the biggest hurdles to understanding multithreaded code is that your intuition (and mine) is often wrong when you add the complexities of multithreading.

Comment: Editing my post to share the actual numbers from the chrono functions, and some output from htop. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting the code;  It doesn’t compile on my machine (Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)).  Love standards.

I hacked it into a C version, and your problem appears to be false sharing; that is each thread is hitting its “seed” entry a lot, but because memory caches aggregate adjacent locations into “lines”, your cpus are spending all of the time copying these lines back and forth.   If you change your definition of “seed” to something like:

```
struct  myseed {
      unsigned seed;
      unsigned dont_share_me[15];
};
```

you should see the scalability you expect.   You might want to do the same to your struct counts.
Typically, malloc makes this adjustment for you, so if you stamp your ‘per thread’ context into a bag and malloc it, it returns properly cache aligned locations.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable insight. I compiled with clang on 64 bit arch linux using the -std=c++11 and -pthread flags. According to the very limited research I've done, it makes sense that multithreading would be funky across systems in C++.

In your suggestion, would dont_share_me just be an empty buffer to keep the seeds isolated in memory?

Comment: I should also ask, for the sake of my continuing education and independence, what tools did you use to analyze the execution of my code? How did you know that the threads were accessing my seed variable so much?

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam, but I also wanted to mention that I did what you suggested and changed my seed to a struct with an empty buffer, and it reduced the average time on 10 threads from ~70s to ~25s.

Comment: tools: eyes.   I’ve been working on concurrent systems for 30 years.  I verified your results, then replaced rand_r() with an increment in case it was interlocking, which was my first guess. Then I added counters on the two inner loops, to verify that they weren’t scaling with #threads .  Then I went looking for cache effects; and noticed the seed array.